# How to connect microSD card or external USB hard drive to Redmi 10C

Tags: usb, sd-card, usb-on-the-go, redmi, disk-drive

I've only ever had Redmi smartphones. First a 4A, then a 6, now a 10C. The first two both used microUSB and the new one uses USB-C. The 4A was a Chinese version and the later two are both international versions.

On one or both of the old ones I was able to connect an external hard drive and microSD card using a USB-OTG (on-the-go) adapter along with either a USB hard drive cable or USB to microSD adapter. I thought I had connected one or the other to my new phone but now I'm not certain.

Currently I can't figure out any way to get my Redmi 10C to recognize any external storage I connect. I've tried with the cable that came with my Seagate hard drive, and with two different microSD cards and two different microSD to USB A adapters via a USB A to USB C adapter. All these cables, adapter, and drives are verified working on my laptop.

My phone is in developer mode and USB debugging is enabled. I downloaded an app that claims to check if an Android phone is OTG-compatible and it says the phone is compatible.

I believe that USB-C includes OTG so that unlike with microUSB, no special OTG adapter is needed any more.

I have updated the MIUI and Android versions on the Redmi 10C at least once and I think twice since I bought it a bit over a year ago. I've looked through all the settings

Am I missing something? Do I still need a special OTG cable even with USB-C? Does the Redmi 10C not support OTG even though the app says it does? Could one of the OS updates have affected it? Could it be a difference between the international version of MIUI vs the Chinese version?

Does someone have a definitive answer? Are there some steps I can follow to narrow it down to fewer possibilities?